# how to output datetime with timezone offset in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime

I have a datetime stored in table with timezone offset to 'America/New_York' in MySQL.

I wanted to display SQL query output as "year-month-date'T'24Hour:Minute:Second.microseconds(+/-)offset" format.

```
Example 1: 2017-05-01T15:02:44.372+0500

Example 2: 2017-05-01T15:02:44.372+0000

Example 3: 2017-05-01T15:02:44.372-0530
```

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ('2022-02-08T14:30:00.123', 'UTC', 'UTC'), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s');
```

I don't find any option to include timezone offset and fraction in the SQL's output.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but also keep in mind that `timezone` and `offset` are not the same thing. Timezones with daylight saving time will have multiple different offsets based on the current date.